# Why textbox click event not firing

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a textbox and it's readonly. When I click on I want it to call my button click event:

```
private void tbFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //btnBrowse_Click(sender, e);
    MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

When click on the textbox, nothing happens. How do I fix it?

**Update:**

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFile();
}

private void tbFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //btnBrowse_Click(sender, e);
    if (tbFile.Text != "")
    {
        openFile();
    }
}

public void openFile()
{
    var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    FD.Filter = "DBF Files|*.DBF";
    FD.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";

    if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fileToOpen = FD.FileName;
        tbFile.Text = fileToOpen;
    }
}
```

When I hit browse button and select a file, the browse file window comes up again. So it's appearing twice now and the textbox click is still not working.

Comment: Have you attached your method to the textbox click event?

Comment: In the properties of your textbox items check the attaching event for click

Comment: Isn't that what my code is showing? `tbFile` is the name of the textbox. I doubt it's something wrong with the event because the messagebox doesn't show either.

Comment: Do you have `Click="tbFile_Click"` in your XAML? Because using the name C# won't trigger it. C# Must reference to it, using that Click command event.

Comment: It's a WinForm application.

Comment: @SiKni8 No - your code *doesn't* show that you have attached an event to the click handler. It simply shows you have created a new method that could be attached.

Comment: Readonly or disabled?

Comment: @SiKni8: you're opening the `OpenFileDialog` to select a file if the file was already chosen: `tbFile.Text != ""`. I assume you want `tbFile.Text == ""`.

Comment: the textbox is READONLY, I am wondering if that's why it's not working :/

Comment: Yes sorry, I changed it to this: `if (tbFile.Text.Length < 0)
            {
                openFile();
            }` and still nothing :/

Comment: A `TextBox.Text.Length` is never `< 0`. Can you show your actual code instead?

Comment: I will update my question with the code.

Comment: @SiKni8 If it's enabled and readonly, it should work; I tested that. You need to confirm in the Properties pane in the form designer that a) it's definitely enabled, and b) tbFile_Click is definitely assigned to the Click event. Another thing to bear in mind is that if some *containing* control is disabled, the textbox will be disabled. When you click in the textbox, does it show a blinking insertion point?

Comment: Everyone, for some reason in the Designer file the click event wasn't added automatically... I added this line: `this.tbFile.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.tbFile_Click);` and it's finally working!!! :) Thanks... everyone.

Comment: Right, so what I said 15 minutes ago...

Comment: I agree and I upvoted your response :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason that can be inferred from the information you provided why you shouldn't trigger the openFile() method when you click on the tbFile control.

The fact that the textbox is set to readonly does **not** stop it from raising the click event in any way.

The only possibility is that the method is not assigned to the click event of the control.

Make sure in the event properties of the control that the click event is indeed assigned to the "tbFile_Click" method.

Just because there exsits a method that's called the same as a control but has "_Click" added does not make it get executed unless you specifically tell c# you want to associate that method with the click event of the control.

When you assign the method through the event window, C# generates a code file behind the scenes that adds the callback to that specific event.

Comment: +1 for the clear explanation as to *why* this must be verified.

Comment: Another possibility would be a parent of the textbox being disabled. But that didn't turn out to have been the case, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the btnBrowse.PerformClick() method to simulate a user click, instead of calling the handler.

Comment: Instead of `btnBrowse.PerformClick` he should create a method like  `Browse` which can be called from wherever he wants.

Comment: PerformClick triggers an actual Click event. This creates a new EventArgs and all that stuff, so it's not exactly the same. I'm not saying that using a method isn't recommended, just not the same. If you want to trigger the same behavior from two event handlers, you should use a function, but also, if you want to simulate a user click, should use PerformClick().

What you shouldn't do under no circumstance, is calling to an event handler from another control's handler, and even worse if you pass the same EventArgs object.

Comment: That's an ugly way to prevent OOP. You'll never be able to reuse this "method" if it's an event-handler which requires a button.

Comment: Still not the same. Build a method, use it, reuse it. Still, it's not the same to **emulate** (that's the key word on this) a user click. Use them both, there's no problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

The default I got from VS 2013 was a 'MouseClick' function so this works:

```
    private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        MyAwesomeFunction(sender);
    }

    private void tbFile_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {     
        MyAwesomeFunction(sender);
    }

    private void MyAwesomeFunction(object sender)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
```

Comment: Make sure the event handler is attached to the TextBox using the 'Events' tab of the properties window.

Comment: I have the same issue with .NET 3.0 on VS2019 and a LineNumberingTextBox. The events are associated in the Events tab.
Both _Click() and _MouseClick() don't work.